# Can other apps play music from my Google Music library?

Tags: google-play-music

I have uploaded my song collection to Google Play Music, and use my phone to listen to them.

Now, if I copy the original music files directly to my phone storage, I can then use any app I want to play them. But what about music synced via Google Play Music?

If I download the songs to my phone in offline mode, can any other app be used to play the same collection (just like with the files), or are they only accessible by Google Play Music app?

Comment: Gear music player accesses you google play music account

Answer (score 7):

They're only accessible from Google Play Music. It stores them somewhere in the internal space of the app, not in the music library of the phone. There is no way to tell the app to move the file somewhere else at the moment, and no way that I'm aware off to point other app to that specific folder.

That's the main reason why I don't use Google Play Music. I want to be in control of my music folder.

Comment: However, it seems you *can* download the songs in mp3 format with a computer, and then then transfer to the phone. But that is rather cumbersome and silly.

Comment: Yes silly indeed. I don't want to have to do that, especially since my music collection is 12GB big... I suppose Google wants to move all of us "to the cloud" instead of using local storage. I'm not sure I like that. When WiFi is available for free everywhere on Earth, maybe :)

Comment: Not really a bandwidth problem for me (3G flows fast enough) but I just want control over which app I use for playing my music. Google Play Music app, for example, doesn't display the lyrics and doesn't have the organizing capabilities I want. But at least I can transfer the most relevant files manually to phone (not that hard using a file exporer like EZ from local NAS) so they are accessible by any music app, and then have Google Play Music app for the rest of my music library. Only, it's a bit cumbersome, and not possible on the go. :( Still, better than nothing...

Answer (score 1):

It appears that this is possible in Lollipop using the API's Google Play Music has implemented for use with Android TV. We'll see how many music player apps support it.

Answer (score 0):

Cloud streaming from Google Music is available through Tomahawk for Android.

Might have to join beta
https://www.tomahawk-player.org/#page-about

Answer (score -1):

You can. Try [doubleTwist Music Player](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.doubleTwist.androidPlayer). Just so you know, this feature requires ROOT.

p.s. I don't know if this feature is still available, I haven't used it for a while now.

Comment: You can with most other players too, as long as you are rooted - rooting is required to be able to see the pinned (downloaded files).